# Is this not a moth?

Tags: pest-control

I apologise for the terrible photographs. I tried many times and can not shoot better ones.

I came back from vacation and moths (I assume) came creeping out of two packages containing oatmeal and rice respectively. I bought pheromonic traps for moths attacking food stuffs, but they have not caught a single one, although they are inches from it. So, I wonder, are these no moths:

Here slain:
[[image: `[![Dead moth?]]

Here alive:
[image]

I notice they don't match the colour of any food stuffs moth mentioned [here](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebensmittelmotte).

The slain moths wingspan (distorted as it is) equals the width of my thumb.

Comment: Well, they are definitely moths of some sort, but I wouldn't dare identifying them from those photos (maybe try in better lighting?). Since they came out of food packages, that makes me think it's likely that they live there. Have you checked for larvae? I'd recommend sealing the packages.

Comment: It is a moth.  Width of the thumb is big for a moth that attacks food, at least in the US.  Pheromones are specific to specific species of insects.  Otherwise you would show up ready to mate and find something of a different species waiting.  You could freeze the packages for a day or 2 to kill anything in them.

Comment: @Will thanks. Already threw away everything I thought they could reach, but I am still worried